# Shannon's Theorem 4 on Entropy of an Information Source

Tags: information-theory, entropy

In Shannon's paper "A Mathematical Theory of Communication," section I.7 "The Entropy of an Information Source," he discusses some results regarding the entropy $H$.

In theorem 3 he states the following

> Theorem 3: Given any$\epsilon$ > 0 and$\delta$ > 0, we can find an $N_0$ such that the sequences of any length $N \ge N_0$ fall into two classes:
>
> 1. A set whose total probability is less than $\epsilon$.
> 2. The remainder, all of whose members have probabilities satisfying the inequality
>    $$\big| \frac{\log p^{-1}}{N} - H \big| < \delta$$

Then he introduces theorem 4 as below

> A closely related result deals with the number of sequences of various probabilities. Consider again the sequences of length $N$ and let them be arranged in order of decreasing probability. We define $n(q)$ to be the number we must take from this set starting with the most probable one in order to accumulate a total probability $q$ for those taken.
>
> Theorem 4:
> $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\log n(q)}{N} = H$$
> when $q$ does not equal $0$ or $1$.

I don't understand the definition of $n(q)$ here and what he meant by accumulating a total probability $q$, did he mean adding up the probabilities of the sequences starting with the most probable one to the least until we reach $q$? Or did he mean multiplying them to get the probability of the intersection of these sequences (assuming independence)?

Also, what does the function $n(q)$ tell us about the information source? And what does this theorem imply?

I'd also appreciate a proof of theorem 4 if possible.

Comment: See [this discussion](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/the-entropy-of-information-source.682038/).

Comment: They mean the former: each possible $N$-length sequence $s = x_1^N$ has a probability $p(s)$. Order these in decreasing order, and build up a set $S_N(q)$ by adding in sequences in this order until $\sum_{s \in S_N(q)} p(s)$ crosses $q$. Let $n(q)$, or I guess $n_N(q)$ might be better, be the number of sequences you added. Then $\frac1 N\log n_N(q) \to H$ for any $q \in (0,1)$.

Comment: The interpretation of this, and results like this, is more-or-less the point of Shannon's paper, which also includes a proof in Appendix 3 (see the paragraph after the statement).  You can ask specific questions you have about the proof or the interpretation, but generally asking for an explanation and proof of these things is strange if you have the source of these statements to read already. In other words, what precisely do you not understand about the interpretation of the theorem and its proof, as presented in Shannon's paper? Tell us exactly where you are stuck.